# Boost Elastic Search results at the query time based on the last indexed time

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to figure out how to boost the relevancy of search results based on the last indexed time. So, if there are multi matches for a search query, I need to boost the results based on the last indexed timestamp of the doc.

I have attempted to follow the documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-boost.html), and tried to execute few queries but not sure how to pass the field name and its value.

```
GET code_sourcenodedupefilecontractv4_1421_shared_5dd3788f-2d0a-4a49-b679-98bbf519013e/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "originalContent": "sample"
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "linear": {
            "indexedTimeStamp": {
              "scale": "30d",
              "decay": 0.5
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

While executing the above query in kibana, I am getting following message:

```
"failed_shards": [
  {
    "shard": 0,
    "index": "code_sourcenodedupefilecontractv4_1421_shared_5dd3788f-2d0a-4a49-b679-98bbf519013e",
    "node": "UX5mwT1sT_a2QuqeFG-JUw",
    "reason": {
      "type": "query_shard_exception",
      "reason": "failed to create query: {\n  \"function_score\" : {\n    \"query\" : {\n      \"match\" : {\n        \"originalContent\" : {\n          \"query\" : \"sample\",\n          \"operator\" : \"OR\",\n          \"prefix_length\" : 0,\n          \"max_expansions\" : 50,\n          \"fuzzy_transpositions\" : true,\n          \"lenient\" : false,\n          \"zero_terms_query\" : \"NONE\",\n          \"auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query\" : true,\n          \"boost\" : 1.0\n        }\n      }\n    },\n    \"functions\" : [\n      {\n        \"filter\" : {\n          \"match_all\" : {\n            \"boost\" : 1.0\n          }\n        },\n        \"linear\" : {\n          \"indexedTimeStamp\" : {\n            \"scale\" : \"30d\",\n            \"decay\" : 0.5\n          },\n          \"multi_value_mode\" : \"MIN\"\n        }\n      }\n    ],\n    \"score_mode\" : \"multiply\",\n    \"max_boost\" : 3.4028235E38,\n    \"boost\" : 1.0\n  }\n}",
      "index_uuid": "U6os7SW0QuqOuuS3sASCrg",
      "index": "code_sourcenodedupefilecontractv4_1421_shared_5dd3788f-2d0a-4a49-b679-98bbf519013e",
      "caused_by": {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Can't load fielddata on [indexedTimeStamp] because fielddata is unsupported on fields of type [date]. Use doc values instead."
      }
    }
  }
]"
```

The value of the field(indexedTimeStamp) stored in elastic search is :

```
"indexedTimeStamp": {
        "type": "date",
        "store": true,
        "doc_values": false,
        "format": "epoch_second"
      },
```

Am I missing something here?

**[EDIT]:** If the `doc_value` is `false`, then we can not sort or aggregate on that field. It is limitation from the elastic search side. I tried with creating new index with the `doc_value` as `true` and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `doc_value` is `false`, then we can not sort or aggregate on that field. Neither we can update the field. It is limitation from the elastic search side. I tried with creating new index with the `doc_value` as `true` and it worked as expected.

More information [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#updating-field-mappings).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `field_value_factor` here because it can take only a number as an argument. You have to use other functions, for instance `gauss`, to prioritize newer records.

It might look somewhat like this:

```js
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "content": "sample"
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "gauss": {
            "indexedTimeStamp": {
              "origin": "now",
              "scale": "30d"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```